# Replace line in Richtextbox VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

This line pops up in my RTB and it generates different characters, it's in their a few times

> "@search_pointer": "2b63f3fdae7f4d00a1273380938f6e8be9f858aa626c36212617a153046ebebf8f71295e81a0578b9a12b7683480728514336e6b66fcd0aa9a138c8867b9175caa504f55e1c02e29427cf0bc4512c546f9e5d60338cfff9a3fde3281140868bffa32ba9cf5d5192200d2b21c6dfb0c734ccb3b5a69f38532ae37937672722302",

I would just like to replace the whole line by finding `@search_pointer`

This is what I have

```
Dim pattern As String = "("@search_pointer":.*",)"
    RichTextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, pattern, String.Empty)
```

but obviously it is throwing up errors, Yes I am a noob

Comment: The c# string concatenation operator is `+`.

Comment: So how do I fix this?

Comment: By learning about string concatenation and why you need it.  I'm an not www.learnVBin21days.com.

Comment: @Dan-o this is **VB.Net** not **C#**.

Comment: Can somebody help me with this? It seems simple and Dan-o is probably the least help ever.

Comment: The VB string concatenation operator is `&`.

Comment: Dan-o Maybe if you would show me how to use this, I could learn it, like most answers people usually provide code that helps the OP

Comment: I gave you a place to start.  If you can't figure out string concatenation you don't have any business being anywhere near a compiler.  Go do your homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the `""` whenever you want to use the double quote in a string:

```
Dim pattern As String = """@search_pointer"":.*,"
```

By the way, check you pattern.

All the best.

Comment: Thank you, someone useful on this site. I do have a question tho

I put your code in

Dim pattern As String = "(" & @search_pointer & ":.*"",)"
        RichTextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, pattern, String.Empty)


and now I get 2 errors

expression expected
pattern is not declared

I am obviously a beginner and just wanna know how this works.

Comment: So, what is "search_pointer", is it a variable declared in your program? what is its type?

Comment: https://api.pipl.com/search/v4/?email=sairwee%40gmail.com&key=sample_key

Right here you can see that, I am basically just trying to parse this RTB. My RTB puts them in lines and I just wanna delete that whole line. sorry its 3 lines

Comment: If you have  skype I can give you my teamviewer and let you see it.

Comment: What about now, try the edited answer. It works well with me.

Comment: Sorry man still doing it, hmmm : http://prntscr.com/6e5g6u , http://prntscr.com/6e5ge6

Comment: Sorry, but it works with me for the RTB contents you have provided in the link.
you can give your email, and I will send you the source code.

Comment: Or, you can find my source code through this link.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1jw5hjccp7dvl11/TestVB.zip?dl=0

Comment: Wish you had skype, cause yours isn't working either, but its cool I gave you a checkmark

Comment: send me your TeamViewer credentials to taher_alraboee@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

Check the example below:

```
Const Data As String = """tag1"":""tag1 value"", ""tagReplace"" : ""tagReplace value"", ""tag2"":""tag1 value"""

Private Function RegexReplace(ByRef searchPointer As String) As String
    Dim pattern As String = "(""" & searchPointer & """\s*:.*""\s*,)"
    Dim res As String = Regex.Replace(data, pattern, String.Empty)
    Return res
End Function
```

Note I included a `\s*` to ignore the whitespaces.

Usage:

```
RegexReplace("tagReplace")
```

It will remove the **tagReplace** tab from original string.

I hope it helps.